# Não consigo criar um projeto do Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Eu consigo criar projetos do Laravel nas versões 8, 7 e 6 com o Composer. Porém, ao tentar criar um projeto na versão 5.7 ou até mesmo na 5.8, o console apresenta um erro.

E o erro apresentado é:
`[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.7.* in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.`

Estou usando o PHP 8.0.0 e o Laravel Installer 4.2.4

Retirei o código para criar o projeto, na própria documentação do Laravel.

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.7.*"`

Comment: O Laravel 5.7 pode não ser compatível com o PHP 8…, caso, ainda assim, queira insistir. Use a *flag* `ignore-platform-req` para ignorar a validação do *composer*. Ex: `composer create-project --ignore-platform-req php laravel/laravel example-app 5.7.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Gabriel! Somente versões posteriores ao Laravel 6 tem suporte para o Php 8, como a [documentação](https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-php-8-support) diz. Caso realmente precise criar um projeto Laravel na versão 5.7, instale o Php 7.4 em sua máquina.